# How to use RegEx regarding second instance and negation

Tags: .net, regex

RegEx noob here. I have the following problem.

I want to search for the following string in xml files (a link containing a guid, hash, and id). Here is an example:

`<link href="6e18f2dc-1d66-4e7e-b6e7-4a68a4217feb#SectionId">`

I want to replace the string so I have (hash and id only):

`<link href="#SectionId">`

I also want to make sure my regular expression search/replace pattern ignores the following (a link with just the guid):

`<link href="a1c52afd-e6a6-4eca-8e6f-d38b0b4f5d48">`

I've been able to accomplish the above with SR32 using SR32 search/replace syntax:

Search: `href="*#*">!(href="*">!(#))`

Replace: `href="#%2">`

How do I accomplish the above using RegEx syntax (from the .NET RegEx class)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
string[] inputs = 
{
    "<link href=\"6e18f2dc-1d66-4e7e-b6e7-4a68a4217feb#SectionId\">",
    "<link href=\"6e18f2dc-1d66-4e7e-b6e7-4a68a4217feb\">"
};

string pattern = @"(?<=<link\s+href="")[^#]+(#.+?)(?="">)";

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
}
```

The `$1` replacement pattern refers to the first group, which is the #ID portion.
The pattern breakdown is:

- `(?<=<link\s+href="")`: look-behind to match (but not consume) the beginning of the link tag, followed by at least one whitespace character, then the href text, equal sign and double quote.
- `[^#]+`: match any character except the `#` character, one or more times. This could be replaced with a pattern to match GUIDs if you want to be stricter about it.
- `(#.+?)`: match and capture the `#` char followed by any character, one or more times and as few characters as possible.
- `(?="">)`: finally, look-ahead for the double-quote and the greater than angle bracket.

The `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` is used to match regardless of the case of the "link" and "href" texts.

For a stricter pattern you can include the GUID pattern:

```
string guidPattern = @"[a-f0-9]{8}-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}";
string pattern = @"(?<=<link\s+href="")" + guidPattern + @"(#.+?)(?="">)";
```

You can join them together but I broke them apart for clarity. The rest of the code would be the same.

The GUID pattern is repetitive. `[a-f0-9]{8}-` uses a character class to specify the possible hexadecimal values, namely the range of A-F characters and 0-9 range. The character class has to be repeated 8 times for the first part, followed by a dash. `(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}` is similar, and occurs 3 times. The `(?: ... )` part means match but don't capture the pattern.

Comment: Hi Ahmad, thanks for the very useful feedback. So basically we have a C# tool that's a wrapper for RegEx, so all I need to do is provide the search string and the replace string. Based on your input above can I use the following search/replace strings? **Search:** `"(?<=<link\s+href="")[^#]+(#.+?)(?="">)"`, **Replace:** "$1"

Comment: @Keith yes, that should work as long as the wrapper doesn't do anything unexpected with those parameters. Notice the `@` symbol preceding my patterns. That's a C# verbatim string literal, so backslashes are already escaped and the double quotes are escaped by specifying them twice... if you're not using C# to pass the pattern to the tool, or chose not to use the verbatim string literal, you'll need to escape backslashes and double quotes yourself, such as `(?<=<link\\s+href=\")[^#]+(#.+?)(?=\">)`

Answer (score 1):

Are the tags always exactly like that, with only the one attribute?  If so, this should work:

search: `<link\s+href="[0-9A-Fa-f-]+(#\w+)">`

replace: `<link href="$1">`

The `$1` captures both the hash symbol and the ID.  In fact, you can use capturing groups to retain all the parts you want to keep.  For example:

search: `(<link\s+href=")[0-9A-Fa-f-]+(#\w+">)`

replace: `$1$2`

`$1` is everything before the GUID and `$2` is everything after it.  A quick look at the [SR32](http://www.funduc.com/search_replace.htm) docs reveals that everything you match with wildcards (I can't bring myself to call them regexes) is captured automatically.  In .NET as in most other flavors, you have to use a capturing group for that.  (There's also a non-capturing variant, `(?: )`, that groups without capturing like SR32's round brackets do.)

There are many other differences.  If your only "regex" experience so far has been with SR32, you have a lot to unlearn. ;)

Comment: Nice solution, Alan! And yes, I need to un-brainwash myself from SR32 so I can become RegEx worthy. :-)